# How can i create new pinned shortcut in win7 shortcut at the first position? ( the left side of the taskbar)

Tags: windows, winapi

When i create a taskbar shortcut in win7 . its default position is at the end ( the right side of the taskbar). can i create a shortcut using i_shell_link and determine the specific location of this shortcut in the task bar ?

Comment: Surely it's up to the user to decide where the shortcut lives

Comment: I mean on programming ... i want to determine this

Comment: Yes I know what you meant. But I have a suspicion that MS will have designed the system so that only the user can decide. They tend to be quite picky about what is allowed programmatically in relation to taskbar, notification area etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Note  Applications cannot programmatically pin themselves to the taskbar. That functionality is reserved strictly for the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692(VS.85).aspx

Doing so would make [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) cry.

Comment: actually applications can programmatically pin themselves to the taskbar. i did it with the following commands:

Comment: int result = reinterpret_cast<int>(ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarpin", shortcut,
      NULL, NULL, 0));

Comment: And now you've annoyed your users.

Comment: yep - but what about - set the position in the taskbar ?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of this anyhow. Your program is not the most important and awesome one out there. If the user wants to use your program and use it enough, they will pin it and place it where they want on the bar.

Comment: If you are able to write an Installer, you can put checkboxes into the Installer's configuration: "Create Desktop Icon", "Create StartMenu Icon" and "Create Taskbar Icon". So the user can chose where he wants the program to be "pinned". I cannot see why Raymond Chen should cry? But the trick with ShellExecute() does not work anymore in Windows 10.